# Set conditions to a field in Django Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my Models:

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class TestModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.TextField()
    field2 = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeinkeyField(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Let the `role`  field can have values `role1`, `role2`, and `role3`

and I want to restrict the `TestModel` having `owner with role=role3`

Comment: Check the [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) option on model fields. And check the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) option for `ForeignKey` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) option on model fields to limit the options available to a user (it changes the form field's widget from a `TextInput` widget to a `Select` widget). Note that this adds validation for these values when `cleaning` the model, it doesn't enforce this at the database level. It works when you use a `ModelForm` and then run `is_valid()` on the form for example.

And you can set the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) option for `ForeignKey` fields. This will restrict the choices offered to the user in the corresponding form field when creating a `ModelForm`. Again, this is not enforced at database level, and it does not add any validation to the model. You'll have to add your own validation either on the form or on the model, e.g. by [overriding the model's `clean` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) or by [overriding the model form's `clean_owner` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).

So on your model, you could do this:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.owner and not self.owner.role == 'role3':
        raise ValidationError({'owner': 'Owner must have role3'}, code='invalid')
```

Comment: I've updated my `ForeignKey field` as 

`owner = models.ForeinkeyField(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to = {'role': role3})` 

still its not validating any request. It is still just accepting any kind of user

Comment: @Sreenath limit_choices_to only filters choices when using ModelForm, does not enforce rules for insertion. You'll still need to handle validation when using that.

Comment: Added the validation instructions for `limit_choices_to`, thanks @OzgurAkcali.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict possible values for role field;

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('role1', 'Role 1'),
        ('role2', 'Role 2'),
        ('role3', 'Role 3'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

To restrict TestModel owners to role3, I don't think there is a way to force it on the database level, but If you're using Django Rest Framework, you can force it on the application level by writing a custom permission class to the view that is responsible for creating TestModel entries to let only users with role3 be the owner for an instance of a TestModel. It would look like this:

```
class TestModelPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == 'create':
            return request.user.role == 'role3'

        return True
```